# Не знаю как реализовать, нужно реализовать нестандартную пагинацию Djangо. Помогите

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

В Django и Python я новичок, пишу пока основываясь на видео уроках и скромных познаниях. Решил потренироваться и переписать сайт написанный ранее на Yii 2, но столкнулся с проблемой которую не могу пока никак решить. Надеюсь на помощь опытных программистов.
Есть модель статьи, есть вьюха в которой я вывожу конкретную статью в шаблоне, где в конце есть нестандартная пагинация, в ней выводится ссылка на следующую либо предыдущую статьи, название статьи и изображение.

Во view я использую класс, вот такой код:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from blog.forms import SubscriberForm
from blog.models import Article
from blog.utils import ObjectDetailMixin

class ArticleDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
    model = Article
    template = 'blog/article_detail.html'
```

вот такой код в миксине:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class ObjectDetailMixin:
model = None
template = None

def get(self, request, slug):
#тут я получаю из базы статью по slug
    obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, slug__iexact=slug)
#отсюда пытаюсь реализовать нестандартную пагинацию, я по id категории
#дергаю из базы все статьи с таким же categoty_id

    articles = self.model.objects.filter(category_id=obj.category.id)

#отсюда затык, мне нужно получить что-то типа prev_article_page и 
#next_article_page с данными, мой код не работает при каждой итерации 
#не добавляет единицу

    for article in articles:
        if article.category_id == obj.category_id:
            z = 0
            next_article = articles[z + 1]
            z += 1
            prev_article = articles[z - 1]
            break
    return render(request, self.template, context= {self.model.__name__.lower(): obj, 'next_article': next_article, 'prev_article': prev_article})
```

в HTML-шаблоне код пагинатора такой:

```html
<div id="single-pagination" class="img-pagination">
            <ul>
                    <li class="prev">
                        <a href="{% url 'articles_list_url' %}{{ prev_article.slug }}" style="background-image:{{ MEDIA_URL }}({{ prev_article.article_image }});">
                            <div class="overlay-caption">
                                <span>Previous Post</span>
                                <h4 class="post-name"><strong>The Right Thing To Do</strong></h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="next">
                        <a href="{% url 'articles_list_url' %}{{ next_article.slug }}" style="background-image:url(files/uploads/900x600-light.jpg);">
                            <div class="overlay-caption">
                                <span>Next Post</span>
                                <h4 class="post-name"><strong>Life Spent Living Across the Country</strong></h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Мне нужно, что бы при каждом переходе на следующую либо предыдущую страницы ключ articles соответственно либо уменьшался либо увеличивался на единицу чтобы получать нужную модель статьи. Возможно это как то по другому можно реализовать помогите, пожалуйста, возможно есть готовое решение. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если вы хотите вывести "Похожие статьи", то пагинация здесь не при чём.

Comment: Narnik Gamarnik, а в каком направлении рыть? Можете подсказать, направить. Просто уперся и 5 день не могу понять что делать

Comment: Я думаю, что ваши ваши посты должны быть объединены тэгами.

Comment: Посты объединены категориями, проблема в другом, я получаю список статей из базы отфильтрованных по категории, к примеру их 5, и если я прохожусь по списку циклом for, он мне выдает все 5 статей, а мне в шаблоне нужно получить и вывести в блоке < li class="prev"> ссылку на 1 статью из цикла которая предшествует отображенной, а в блоке <li class ="next"> ссылку на статью из цикла следующую за отображенной и цикл должен прерваться, а не выдать мне все 5 статей из списка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для себя нашел следующее решение, вдруг кому пригодиться.В файле views.py использую встроенный класс-контроллер DetailViev, в котором переопределил метод get_context_data:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage
from django.views.generic import View, DetailView, TemplateView
from blog.models import Article, Tag, Category

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
model = Article
template_name = 'blog/article_detail.html'
slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.object.category is not None:
        context['articles'] = Article.objects.filter(category=self.object.category).order_by('id')
        for n, article_page in enumerate(context['articles']):
            if article_page.id == self.object.id:
                try:
                    context['prev_page'] = context['articles'][n-1]
                except AssertionError:
                    context['prev_page'] = None
                try:
                    context['next_page'] = context['articles'][n+1]
                except IndexError:
                    context['next_page'] = None
                break
         return context
```

Мне нужно было получить списка QuerySet отфильтрованную предыдущую и последующие статьи, фильтрация происходила по категории.

в HTML-шаблоне код следующий:

```html
 <div id="single-pagination" class="img-pagination">
            <ul>
                {% if prev_page %}
                <li class="prev">
                    <a href="{% url 'articles_list_url' %}{{ prev_page.slug }}" style="background-image:url({{ prev_page.article_cover_image.url }});">
                        <div class="overlay-caption">
                            <span>Предыдущая статья</span>
                            <h4 class="post-name"><strong>{{prev_page.title }}</strong></h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li class="prev">&nbsp;</li>
                {% endif %}
            {% if next_page %}
                <li class="next">
                        <a href="{% url 'articles_list_url' %}{{ next_page.slug }}" style="background-image:url({{ next_page.article_cover_image.url }});">
                            <div class="overlay-caption">
                                <span>Следующая статья</span>
                                <h4 class="post-name"><strong>{{ next_page.title }}</strong></h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                <li class="next">&nbsp;</li>
            {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
```